# How to fetch data using indexing by jsonb data in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working On Postgresql 9.6,
 Here i am trying to fetch the data from table on behalf of Json key which is jsonb type,
 the data is somthing looks like

```
 [{"name": "gp1", "type": "A"}, {"name": "gp2", "type": "A"}, {"name": "gp2", "type": "A"}]
```

Here modules is column_name and client_modules is table name.

I am also creating the index using below Query

```
create index myindex on client_modules((modules->>'name'));
```

Problem is when i am trying to fetch the data from table using below query

```
SELECT modules FROM client_modules WHERE modules @>'[{"name":"gp1"}]' or modules @> '{"name":"gp1"}';
```

I am able to retreive required data but in this case here my plpgsql query is run on default seqscan index,

I am also execute the script

```
set enable_indexscan = on;
 AND 
set enable_seqscan = off;
```

But still query is not running on my index, when i run the query it is still run on default index.

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL expression indexes, the index condition and the filter condition must match exactly.  Yours do not match.  You indexed on:

```
modules->>'name'
```

But then you searched on:

```
modules @>'[{"name":"gp1"}]'
```

While you know and I know that those two searches are functionally equivalent, the PostgreSQL query planner does not know it. So you have two choices:

1. change your query to look like `WHERE modules->>name ='gp1'
2. create a general GIN index on the whole JSONB field: `CREATE INDEX jsonb_all ON client_modules USING GIN (modules);`